# Dimensional Model

Tags: sql, architecture, db2, dimensional-modeling, erwin

I am working on a Data Migration project. 
The legacy system is IBM Toad DB2, and the target system is MS SQL SERVER Azure. The data at the source system is in XML format. I have to use ERwin, to first create a model and then generate the DDL, and implement it.

The column count is 180 columns.

1. How should I create a Dimensional Model in the above scenario?

Comment: Your question is not clear please provide examples and details.

Answer (score 0):

Some tools (maybe including ERwin, I do not know) can convert XML schemas to data models.

E.g. IBM's InfoSphere Data Architect has such a feature  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS9UM9_9.1.2/com.ibm.datatools.transform.xsd.ldm.doc/topics/cxsd2ldm_transform.html